# Model is not refreshed in Angular UI type-ahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

To replicate the problem [in this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2MKstKJYRFxNJux5TcHW?p=preview), enter anything in the field, select any row and then click on the button "Change Name". You will see that the model is changed but the Angular Type-ahead input field does not reflect the model. Any thoughts?

HTML

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="ds" 
    uib-typeahead="ds as ds.name for ds in queryList($viewValue)" >

  <p>Model: {{ds}}</p>

  <button ng-click="changeName()">Change Name</button>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope,$uibModal) {

    $scope.queryList = function(query) {
        return [ {id: 1, name: "aaa"}, 
                 {id: 2, name: "bbb"},
                 {id: 3, name: "ccc"}]
    };

    $scope.changeName = function(){
      $scope.ds.name = "New name";
    };

});
```

Comment: Use `ng-model="ds.name"` instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/zaRdpKjfc6YhErVmkayi?p=preview

Comment: I can't, because I need the model to have the id AND the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution - to recreate the whole object:

```
$scope.changeName = function(){
  $scope.ds = {
    id: $scope.ds.id,
    name: "New name"
  };
};
```

[PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/05qhkMkJyofexcJc22MN?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="ds.name" 
    uib-typeahead="ds as ds.name for ds in queryList($viewValue)" >
```

Comment: I can't, because I need the model to have the id AND the name